# How to add the date after 3 months

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I want to add the date after the three months for this statement.

```
drt("EntitledEndDate") = row("doc_dt") +
```

The doc_date is 9/

Answer (score 7):

The `AddMonths` function is available. With it you can simply add the number of months in the `DateTime` object. It should be like...

```
drt("EntitledEndDate") = Convert.ToDateTime(row("doc_dt")).AddMonths(3);
```